# Ajax GET request using jQuery returning null in Safari only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, safari

I'm going nuts trying to debug a problem I'm having with Safari only (running 5.1).

I'm doing a simple ajax GET request using jQuery as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_values.cgi",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache","pragma":"no-cache" },
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Fatal Error");
       },
        success: function (data) {
         (do stuff here)
        }
```

This call works fine in all browsers except Safari. The CGI code is returning nicely formatted JSON data and it is parsed quite happily by all other browsers (has been tested with the latest versions of IE, Chrome, and Firefox).

The error Safari is throwing is from the jQuery code - it is "JSON: Unexpected EOF".

It's clear from stepping through the jQuery code using the Safari debugger that Safari is throwing away the returned JSON data completely - it is attempting to parse a null string and thus throws an error.

We have watched the *HTTP* requests going back and forth with message monitoring software and seen that the CGI is clearly creating the message correctly and sending it up to Safari correctly. It's Safari that is throwing away the JSON data.

I have seen other questions on here that talk about empty responses in Safari due to problems with their authentication stack, but adding the no-cache rules to the header as shown above made no difference; changing to a POST type made no difference, either.

Help, I'm pulling my hair out!

Comment: Any chance you could share the JSON being returned by get_values.cgi?

Comment: It looks like this: {"hide_all":"true"} --> that's it.

Comment: It might just be a copy-paste error but I noticed your code is missing the close on the AJAX method call 

    $.ajax({
        ...
    }); //<- this is missing

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, just a copy and paste error - the actual code had the semicolon. Seems like something in the response to the GET is being discarded by Safari - but all other browsers are happy. GAH.

Comment: Is your CGI script properly setting the Content-Type and Content-Length HTTP headers? 

I also see your data properties in the $.ajax() call are empty. Did you just take out the data you're normally sending or are you sending an empty object to the server?

Comment: Sending an empty object - the CGI code does a database query and returns JSON data. We are definitely setting the Content Type but I'm not sure about the Content Length - great idea, I will look into that!

Comment: I have the same problem did anyone find something to solve it ????

Comment: Still no luck, but I haven't had a chance to dig deeper into it lately - we are just working with IE/Chrome/Firefox in the meantime. I think checking the content length of the HTTP message is a good thing to try - haven't had a chance to double check this yet. Please post back if you have any luck!

Answer (score 0):

Probably site is running as http://domain.com (without **www**) and ajax calls is running as http://www.domain.com. And Safari assumes it as cross-domain requests... Try to confirm that version. As a solution can be to force www for example with .*htaccess* ...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue today in Safari 13.1. JSON was being properly returned from a `/php/chat.php` which worked fine when loaded directly. But when loaded by Ajax, it threw "An unexpected error occurred." And as above, exploring the JSON parse found a "JSON: Unexpected EOF" - I'm forced to conclude that Safari is chucking the content.

The first solution I discovered was to rename `/php/chat.php` to `/php/chat/index.php` and load it by Ajax using `/php/chat/` instead.

I came back the next day to try loading `/php/chat`, `/php/chat/` and `/php/chat/index.php` - and *all three* worked. This confused me, as I had been building a theory that the `.php` extension was triggering the error.

So, the second solution I discovered was to rename `/php/chat.php` to anything else. `/php/cht.php` worked, as did `/php/chatt.php` and `/php/chat-dev.php` and `/php/chat-status.php` - figuring that this was too filename-specific to be a Safari bug, I explored the configuration of the Nginx web server to see if I could find an instruction targeted at `chat.php` with no luck.

Exploring the PHP, logging step by step showed no server errors, and proper generation of JSON and sending.